# running "git log" results in an error saying "less: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'"

Tags: git, shell, git-bash

I was introduced software `cmder`, which realy helps a lot coding on win 10. Later when I open git bash, change directory to an existed git repo, trying to logs the previous commition, I got nothing but such output:

```sh
$ git log
'less: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
'less: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I'm sure the repo works well: I tried to initialze a new repo, make some changes, `git add`, `git commit`, and try `git log` again, but the same problem just come out again.

I'm not sure whether `cmder` causes this (no use of git-bash for a pretty long time), but by googling `less: -c: line 0: ...`, some results suggest `cmder` may cause such problem in other zone (not git).

In my understanding, the output maybe refers to an shell script, when executing `git log`, the srcipt will be executed(maybe it's named `less`?); however the script got an syntax error when looking for another `'` matching one in the first line (By the way, command `less` works well individually).

Has anyone have idea how this happen? How should I solve such problem? I'd appreciate for your help!

Comment: Do `git config -l` and look for lines beginning with `pager.`

Comment: Try `git -c core.pager=cat log`. If that works (but dumps lots of output all at once), then your pager configuration is screwed, either `core.pager` or `~/.lesskey` or whatever it is on your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself a few days later and sorry for answering this late.
It turns out that I just modify environment variables and set **HOME** to an unproper position ("C:\Users\Your-Name" by default). Anyone who fall down to the same problem should consider if you modify important envrionment variables as I do.
Thank all the responders for your generous help!